# Bayes' rule in a Markov chain

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a sequence of discrete values from a finite set $V$. Let $A$ be the transition matrix computed by counting instances of $V_i \rightarrow V_j$ from the sequence $X$. Hence, $P(X_{n+1} = V_i | X_n = V_j) = A(i,j)$.

Now, let the events $A = [X_{n+1} = V_i]$ and $B = [X_n = V_j]$. My question is as follows: is $P(A) = P(B)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $P(X_{n+1} = V_i)$? This is either zero or one. Ditto for the conditional probabilities.

Comment: It's the probability that the current event is $V_i$ --- it's not binary since it depends on the $X$

Comment: Jacob: for any events A and B of positive probability, what is the *definition* of P(A|B)? And of P(B|A)? Ergo?

Comment: @Didier: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at. I've updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Forget the update. Quote: *My question is as follows: is P(A|B)=P(B|A) since [meaning: if one assumes that] P(A)=P(B)*. The answer follows from the very definition of P(A|B) and P(B|A), so I am trying to understand what prevents you from seeing it. Once again: if I give you two events A and B, how do you compute P(A|B)?

Comment: @Jacob, I don't see why the probability of $X_{n+1}=V_i$ should equal the probability of $X_n=V_j$.

Comment: @Didier: $P(A|B) = A(i,j)$ where $A$ is determined by observing $X$ as mentioned in the question. I'm sorry if the problem wasn't clear before, but I'm actually asking whether $P(A) = P(B)$.

Comment: You are asking whether P(A)=P(B)??? Well, I can tell you THIS question is NOT in your post... OK, what is your hypothesis? Is it that P(A|B)=P(B|A)?? (I cannot believe one could write *is property Q since property R?* to ask for a proof that *if Q then R*...)

Comment: Jacob: what is your question?

Comment: @Didier: The question is whether P(A) = P(B) but I don't think that's the case

Comment: Sorry, your question does not make sense at all to me. The event A is 'state=i at time=n+1' . The event B is 'state=j at time=n'. How could one say anything about P(A) P(B), knowing only that there is a (general) transition matrix, I cannot imagine.

Comment: Jacob: OK, now we know what we want to prove. But we cannot prove something from nothing, right? Sooo... next step: what is your hypothesis? I see none in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $P(X_n=V_i)=P(X_{n+1}=V_j)$ for every $n$ and every $(i,j)$ is equivalent to the condition that the distribution of $X_n$ is uniform for every $n$, that is, that $P(X_n=V_i)=1/K$ for every $n$ and $i$, where $K$ denotes the size of $V$.

Now, this happens if and only if (1) the distribution of $X_0$ is uniform and (2) the transition matrix $A$ preserves the uniform distribution. Condition (1) means that, for every $i$,
$$
P(X_0=V_i)=1/K.
$$
Condition (2) means that, for every $i$,
$$
\sum_jA(i,j)=1.
$$
Note that the dual condition $\displaystyle\sum_iA(i,j)=1$ is always true.

Answer (score 1):

If your transition matrix is $\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&0\cr}$, so that $X_{n+1}=V_1$ no matter what $X_n$ is, then the probability that $X_{n+1}=V_1$ is $1$, while the probability that $X_n=V_2$ is zero, provided $n\gt1$, so it would appear that in this case $P(A)\ne P(B)$.

Comment: If we can assume homogeneity/ergodicity/whatever property is that means that probabilities are independent of $n$, and we assume we have reached an equilibrium state where each state is occupied at time $n$ according to its equilibrium probability (sorry, don't really know the terminology of Markov chains...) then can we make the statement that for $m\neq n$ we have $P(X_n=i)=P(X_m=j)$ if $i=j$, but otherwise they are not in general equal.

Answer (score 0):

Reversibility is not required. Let's consider a Markov model of a swimmer. The state WEAR_TRUNKS may be followed by ENTER_WATER (or TAKE_SHOWER). Rarely does one WEAR_TRUNKS *after* ENTER_WATER.

Look up [detailed balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance).

Comment: No, that is not my question. I've updated it to make it clearer.